# Hash maps to link several domains into one report - Java Eclipse

Tags: java, hashmap, report

I am new to Java and am using Java Eclipse, so please be kind! I hope I'm going to pose this question correctly so it makes sense.

I have four domains - each domain is pulling data from four different servers, hence the need to have them separate.  But now I need to create a report that links all the data from the four domains into one report.  Someone suggested using hashmaps, which I haven't used before.  My four domains each have two fields that can be used as a key - CostCenter and Serial.  The data being pulled is from machines all over the country.  I need all the data for each machine in one report.

This is all being added to an existing project that creates a webpage with tabs for the user to click on for various tables and get data specific to a location, or to create a report for each page for all machines/locations.  I just need to add a new link for the user to click on that will create this spreadsheet for them.

I've already created the domains (DAO, DAOImpl, DTO, and so on) and then I was going to create the combined report in my MainService.java.  Here are the domains (lists) as declared in my MainService:

```
public List<Volume> getVolumeReport();

public List<BadFmPumps> getBadFmPumpsReport();

public List<BadCorobPumps> getBadCorobPumpsReport();

public List<McService> getMcServiceReport();
```

And here is data being pulled from the databases for each of them (domains):

```
public class Volume {

private String costCenter;
private String DAD;
private String division;
private String model; 
private String serial;
private String numDispensers;
private String colorantSys;
private String CCEGals2017;
private String BACGals2017;
private String CCEGals2018;
private String BACGals2018;
private String DNR2017;
private String DNR2018;
private String DNR2019;
```

---

```
public class BadFmPumps {

private String costCenter; 
private String model; 
private String serial; 
private String badFmPumps;  
private String over10;
private String under10;
```

---

```
public class BadCorobPumps {

private String costCenter; 
private String model; 
private String serial; 
private String badPumpCount;
```

---

```
public class McService {

private String costCenter; 
private String model; 
private String serial; 
private String crChargeTotals; 
private String emgCalls;
```

So I need to pull this data into one report wherever CostCenter + Serial matches.  How do I declare the hashmaps for each object and how do I declare the key?

EDIT ----

I think I have something close here with

```
public List<Volume> getVolumeReport();

Map<String, Volume> VolumeMap = new HashMap<String, Volume>();

for (Volume dispenser : VolumeList)

{

String volumeKey = new StringBuilder().append(Volume.getCostCenter()).append(Volume.getSerial()).toString();

VolumeMap.put(volumeKey, dispenser);

}
```

Is this correct?  I am getting one syntax error - the Map declaration

```
Map<String, Volume> VolumeMap = new HashMap<String, Volume>();
```

is giving me the error

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

Is there something I need to change there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some unusual things in your code. My guess is that you came from C# you are not using proper naming conventions see it here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

You defined your method wrong, the error is not in the Map but the method definition

```
public List<Volume> getVolumeReport(); <-------- this
```

Should be

```
public List<Volume> getVolumeReport() {
```

And then close your method at its end (using `}`).

And inside your FOR you trying to direct access the `Volume` methods when you should use the variable you created: `dispenser`

```
String volumeKey = new StringBuilder()
                           .append(Volume.getCostCenter())
                           .append(Volume.getSerial())
                           .toString();
```

Should be

```
String volumeKey = new StringBuilder()
                           .append(dispenser.getCostCenter())
                           .append(dispenser.getSerial())
                           .toString();
```

Comment: Thank you - this is getting me a lot closer to what I need.

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem?

Comment: Yes and no - adding the brackets does get rid of the syntax error, but now I'm getting ***Abstract methods do not specific a body*** for 

`public List<Volume> getVolumeReport() {`

And now I have to figure out how to loop through and add to each line of the report.

Comment: That should read ***Abstract methods do not specify a body*** above

Comment: So it seems that there are missing code on your question. This error shows up when you define an Abstract class and try to define a method for it. By any chance is your method defined as `public abstract ...` please if so, share your full code in your question so we can help you better.

Comment: Now my hardest problem is how do I loop through each list to add them to ONE report.  Each record should have `costCenter,DAD,division,model,serial,numDispensers,colorantSys,CCEGals2017,BACGals2017,CCEGals2018,BACGals2018,DNR2017,DNR2018,DNR2019,badFmPumps,over10,under10,badPumpCount,crChargeTotals,emgCalls` wherever CostCenter and Serial number match.

Comment: I would create a class ReportVO (value object) fill it with your current objects and use it in whatever you need.